# Two variables in one query - pl/sql procedure

Tags: sql, variables, plsql

I need to update multiple rows using one query or pl/sql procedure

Manually I need to do something like this for each row:

`update item_product set product_no in ('8948061100060064024') where id in (1319180455);`

for different id, update different product_no

I tried pl/sql procedure,

```
DECLARE 
   type ordersIDarray IS VARRAY(5) OF VARCHAR2(10); 
   type simArray IS VARRAY(5) OF VARCHAR2(20); 
   orders ordersIDarray;
   simNo simArray;

BEGIN 
   orders := ordersIDarray('1319180455,1319182309'); 
   simNo := simArray('8948061100060064024','8948061100060064055');

   for i in 1 .. total LOOP
   update item_product set product_no in (simNo(i)) where id in (orders(i));
   end loop;
END;
```

Any ideas how to connect two variables in one query?

Comment: `set product_no in ('8948061100060064024')`  is invalid SQL. Did you mean `set product_no = '8948061100060064024'`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I used both methods and both work, the main problem is syntax of procedure above

Comment: You can't have used that code. The expression `set product_no in ('8948061100060064024')` will result in `ORA-00927: missing equal sign`

Comment: How are your arrays being populated? Is it passed in from the front end (i.e. can't be derived from data already in your database) or is it populated from tables? If the latter, then I'd avoid using arrays at all and simply build a single update statement (probably inside a merge statement) that fetches the data and does the update in one go.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a few product IDs, you can use:

```
update item_product 
    set product_no = case id 
                        when 1 then '8948061100060064024'
                        when 2 then '1234'
                        when 3 then '7890'
                      end
where id in (1,2,3);
```

This has the disadvantage that you need to repeat the values for the `ID` column.

You can get around that by using a MERGE statement with a list of IDs

```
merge into item_product 
using (
   select 1 as id, '8948061100060064024' as product_no from dual union all
   select 2 as id, '1234' from dual union all
   select 3 as id, '7890' from dual
) t on (t.id = item_product.id)
when matched then update 
    set product_no = t.product_no;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I added equal sign after product_no and it worked

Comment: and what do you think about pl/sql procedure? Is it a good idea?

Comment: @truegunner: a cursor or loop is almost always a bad choice if you can do it with a single statement